# Is the monthly supply drop picked up automatically after a while?

Tags: xcom-2

Every month you receive a supply drop, which can be collected over 3 days at a certain spot on the Geoscape.

I ignored that pick up partially and after a while I've received a message saying that all resources have been gathered and new items are available at Resistance HQ. I didn't look at my supplies or the date, when it happened so I neither know whether I got the supplies nor when they expired.

So my question is: Is the monthly supply drop picked up automatically after a while or does it expire and the supplies are lost? How long does it take to expire?

Comment: Pretty sure it expires, can't 100% confirm that right now

Answer (score 5):

The supplies expire after a certain amount of time, just like any other rumor.

The difference being, whenever the Supply Drop disappears (usually because you have picked up the supplies), you get the popup about new items being available at resistance HQ.

In my experience, you don't need to actually pick up the supplies for new items to be available at resistance HQ.

Comment: I'm not so sure, I recently saw a video, where the player let a partially collected supply drop expire and the remainder was added to his total. Any other opinions here? I currently don't have the time to try it out myself.

Comment: @Dulkan Link to the video?

Comment: https://youtu.be/snQik1P9cDM?t=34m48s You can clearly see the supply drop is at 1.5 days remaining, he starts making contact, but the supply drop ticks down as well and provides resources.

Comment: @Dulkan: Curious, can't explain it.